# Exception in GUI thread causing vshost.exe to crash

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, debugging, crash

I think my Visual Studio 2008 (.net 3.5) is corrupted.

If I start a new Windows Forms project in a new solution, add the code

```
double[] x = new double[2];
x[3] = -1.0;
```

to the form_load handler (or a button handler), and try to debug the program, it crashes immediately, not throwing an exception, but actually crashing.

If I put the same code in the form constructor or in Main, an exception gets thrown like normal.

Any ideas what might be going on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't worry, your VS is fine.

The form load handler will (ultimately) be invoked from the Windows message loop, where exception handling is a little different. See [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324653) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am confused how I have never run into this problem before. I've done lots of windows form programming and never run into this before; I'm pretty sure my programs have thrown uncaught exceptions, is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Do only certain functions count as "in windows forms"? Some other way many exceptions get propagated?

Comment: This apparently only happens on 64 bit windows. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/debugger/archive/2010/05/12/visual-studio-debugger-fails-to-catch-unhandled-exception-for-a-windows-form-or-wpf-application.aspx